# Is it possible to add border to line boxes in CSS?

Tags: css

AFAIK, externally a line box resides in a block container that only contains stacking line boxes. Internally a line box is composed of one or more inline-level boxes that fit into one line.

To better understand their relationship, I am wondering if it is possible to add borders to line boxes, not the block container or each individual inline-level boxes.

Example from CSS the definitive guide 4ed:

[image]

Code example (that does not have border for line boxes):

```css
p > span {border: 1px solid black; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<p style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 25px;">
<span>This is text, <em>some of which is emphasized</em>, plus other text</span><br>
<span>which is <strong style="font-size: 50px; vertical-align: 10px;">strongly 
emphasized</strong> and which is</span><br>
<span>larger than the surrounding text.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you explain this with an example of visual?

Comment: @BOZ I don't know yet how to code it up yet, but I attached a screenshot from a book that shows a solid border for the line box and grey background for the inline boxes.

Comment: @wlnirvana You can use pseudo elements to do so, I you can provide with some sample code then I might be able to help ✌

Comment: Sadly, no. CSS provides no mechanism for that.

Comment: @Alohci Is there any browser supporting this via the developer tools?

Comment: Not that I know of.